# Is there possibly a way to disable the use of autocomplete with JS/CSS display none attribute?

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image]I have tried recently to disable the web browsers`autocomplete` function by various means including many `autocomplete off` scenarios, that seem to leave compatibility issues between browsers. So now I'm now trying to figure if I can fix the problem using  `autocomplete` and  `display none` , only I having problems as to figure how to code them together. The code applies to the filter/(search) input function.

JS

```
<body>
<script>
var input, table, rows, noMatches, tr, markInstance;

$(document).ready(function init() {
input = document.getElementById('myInput');
noMatches = document.getElementById('noMatches');

table = document.querySelectorAll('#myTable table tr:first-child');
rows = document.querySelectorAll('#myTable table tr');

markInstance = new Mark(table);
input.addEventListener('keyup', _.debounce(ContactsearchFX, 250));
});    


function ContactsearchFX() {
  resetContent();
  markInstance.unmark({ done: highlightMatches });
}



function resetContent() {
    $('.noMatchErrorText').remove(); 
    //Remove this line to have a log of searches

    //noMatches.textContent = '';
  rows.forEach(function(row) {
    $(row).removeClass('show'); 
  });
}

function highlightMatches() {
  markInstance.mark(input.value, {
    each: showRow,
    noMatch: onNoMatches,
    exclude: ['.nonsearch']
  })
}



function showRow(element) {
//alert(element);
  $(element).parents('tr').addClass('show');                $(element).parents('tr').siblings('tr').addClass('show');
        //Parents incase of several nestings
}



function onNoMatches(text) {
  $('#myInput').after('<p class="noMatchErrorText">No records match: "' +     text +                '"</p>'); 
}



/* Prevents Return/Enter key from doing anything */

$(document).on('submit', 'form', function(e){
/* on form submit find the trigger */
if( $(e.delegateTarget.activeElement).not('input, textarea').length == 0 ){
    /* if the trigger is not between selectors list, return super false */
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
 } 
 });    

    /* Prevents Return/Enter key from doing anything */
```

CSS

```
.input-wrap  {
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

#myInput:invalid ~ .hints {
  display: block;
}



#noMatches:empty, #noMatches:empty + .hints {
  display: none;
}


.style1 tr {
  display: none;
}


.style1 .show {
  display: table-row;
}



#myTable table tr:first-child td mark {
background: orange;
font-weight: bold;
color: black;
}
mark {
background: initial;
}    .style1  {
text-align: left;
}
</style>
```

HTML

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.11/lodash.min.js">
</script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mark.js/8.11.1
/mark.min.js"></script>
<head>
<body>
<div class="input-wrap">
<label>
Search 
<input id="myInput" type="text" required
   placeholder="Search Titles" />
</label>
</div>

<div class="hintsWrap">
<p id="noMatches"></p>
<p class="hints">
Hints: type "Title1", "Title2", "Title3"...
</p>
</div>
<br />
<br />
<br />
<table id="myTable" style="width: 100%" class="style1">
    <tr>
        <td>
<br />
<br />
<table style="width: 100%">
    <tr>
        <td>
        <table style="width: 100%">
            <tr>
                <th class="style1">Type</th>
                <td>type1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th class="style1">Title</th>
                <td>title1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th class="style1">Description</th>
                <td>description1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th class="style1">Date</th>
                <td>date1</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<br />
<br />
        <table style="width: 100%">
            <tr>
                <th class="style1">Type</th>
                <td>type2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th class="style1">Title</th>
                <td>title2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th class="style1">Description</th>
                <td>description2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th class="style1">Date</th>
                <td>date2</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
<br />
 <br />
        <table style="width: 100%">
            <tr>
                <th class="style1">Type</th>
                <td>type3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th class="style1">Title</th>
                <td>title3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th class="style1">Description</th>
                <td>description3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th class="style1">Date</th>
                <td>date3</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

</body>
```

Comment: On your `<form>` just set `<form autocomplete="off">` then add a hidden `<input autocomplete="a_random_string_here_can_be_anything" name="hidden" />` as the first tag in your form.

Comment: @Joel, I have tried that and numerous ideas - which is how Ive ended up coming to a possible ```autocomplete``` working with the ```display none``` solution

Comment: which browsers are you having trouble with specifically?

Comment: All browsers, but mainly between Firefox and Google Chrome @Joel

Answer (score 0):

This is a weird scenario, but for some reason, some browsers don't adhear to the `autocomplete="off"` variable inside forms.

You can do something like this:

```
<form autocomplete="off">
    <input autocomplete="anything_but_false_or_a_valid_value" name="forHackToWork" />
    ...
</form>
```

For Safari:
`spellcheck="false"` is needed.

Comment: There are several browsers that don't fully support autocomplete - [can I use autocomplete](https://caniuse.com/?search=autocomplete)

Comment: @ATD Exactly, this is a hack for bypassing it. Just passing in nonsense values will disable it.

Comment: Again, I have tried that and numerous ideas - which is how Ive ended up coming to a possible ```autocomplete``` working with the ```display none``` attribute. A solution together any ides on this are welcome

Answer (score 0):

Autocomplete is a somewhat work in progress per say. As browsers are become more unified in BOM that is even Microsoft moved towards chromium platform.

In light of the above browsers are moving towards or have move towards completely ignoring attributes on password fields, passwords fields previously had incorporated autocomplete=off for password fields. Some had already extended the same to numbers and lists etc.
The quirk is explained [enter link description here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Turning_off_form_autocompletion)

There seems to be no strait forward hack that may work every where. It is one of those wired things which browsers think tanks are still out trying to bring their head together. Reason being W3C mandates strict implementation of DOM standards but does not bother with what browser features in its BOM. Hence the world of polyfills e.g. header and footer on print page its marathon to control it cross browser. Same is the quirk of autocomplete for some its 'off' for some its 'false' for some its 'chrome-off' etc.

Now coming to you case we have input fields, however no form field. From provides control to the child elements on submission e.g. buttons, fields. Although field with out form is valid HTML as per W3C but it losses control attributes. We then have to seek JS helpers to perform controls. This JS is limited to DOM only not BOM. What is captured in field as autocomplete is BOM scope not DOM. It has happened many times what was entered on site poped up in another site, usually email fields.
[enter link description here](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#form-controls)

What we can do is as suggested in above link place elements that require control to placed inside form tag then set attribute autocomplete=off on both form and desired fields. It would work most of the time how ever there would be some edge cases especially android browser or some funcky browser hybird engine.

**UPDATE: POST THEORY**

Other Chromium based browsers out side of chrome it self seems to respect `autocomplete='off'`. But I tested in chrome the notorious bug is till there, rational because Google had decided that developers were abusing the attribute for their liking so they are ignoring it. Which brings us back to the BOM issue not DOM issue.

Work around is to confuse BOM since we cannot side it out. However there are limitations to it;

- It either has to be applied beforehand browser receives HTML OR before browser even begins building node trees at virtual/light DOM level that is before its painted on screen.
- Or node has to be altered as new entity.

PS form controls are as per scheme of things are tied to field name attributes i.e. `<input names='fieldname'`. that is how BOM pushes autocomplete from one site/page to another. If another page/site is using the same filed name for input browser will autocomplete with what ever it has stored in its field auto fill cache. Ever wonder why deleting history has this delete auto fill form data.
[image]

Work around is to never ever keep the same field attribute name as same for next run. If page is rendered from server side do it then append random time stamp values to the avlue e.g. name='a2323232323' or something on similar lines. Or change it on similar fashion from client side through JS. So when the form is submitted and next time it is rendered BOM will not have any new entry for the form auto fill data to match. Screen shot examples below.

**Usual scenario where autocomplete is ignored**

```
    <form action="" >
  <div class="container">
    <label for="uname"><b>Username</b></label>
    <input id="testi" type="email" placeholder="Enter Username" name="uname" required >
```

From has no autocomplete attribute what so ever, what happens is as following;
On first run autocomplete is not run at all
[image]
But on second run after submitting the form same **uname** field triggers auto complete
[image]
[image]

Workaround now if I was to change the name attribute value lest suppose through jQuery.

```
$('[name ="uname"]').attr('name', 'a'+Date.now());
```

[image]

No autocomplete triggered. Because every time page is painted name atrribute value will be changed.
[image]
the point is we have control over DOM not BOM, what we have done is fooled the BOM through DOM manipulation. Seems idiotic but hey that is nature of things.

So my solution would be combine your workaround with above workaround.

1. Create a hidden field with static name as you have done - don't make it display hidden make it hidden. `<input type="hidden" name='emailme'>`
2. create a visual field with normal type which user views and interacts with - on each load or as per need change the name attribute of this field through JS so autocomplete wont trigger.
3. Then assign onchange event

   ```
   $("#visiblefield").on('change', function() {
     $('#hiddenfield').val($("#visiblefield").val());
   ```

   });

**Why step three is needed**

Since form is sent to to server and since form control is run through name attributes (id is for DOM) on server side lets suppose php or what ever you would not be able to tell the script what POST or GET value to look for since its being changed on the fly. Having a heidden field works as charm as it keeps user interaction way and keeps server side processing in check.

This solution will work in all browsers even the old dusty ones going back IE9+ thats ancient time in browser world.

Hope this helps,dont forget to upvote.

Comment: Again, I have tried that and numerous ideas - which is how Ive ended up coming to a possible autocomplete working with the display none solution I have tried that and numerous ideas - which is how Ive ended up coming to a possible autocomplete working with the display none solution

Comment: I have updated the answer with a possible hack through run time JS manipulation.  Its funny why the obvious wont work but but most ridiculous wold work I would try to add screen shots if possible.

Comment: Works perfect apart from when in Chrome when the browser navigates back and fourth - the page doesn't display what is typed in the filter/(search) input box @Syed

Comment: ...Even though the filter/(search) name term is remembered in the input box

Comment: PS @Syed - Screenshot added

Comment: @Orbit PS when browser is moving back and forth it triggers news paint in most cases i.e. JS would run as stated in answer performing name attribute change on the fly. In others browsers are trying to cut down on network load and pull everything from cache as an painted image similar to what one would expect from what an ISO image file does. Opera is notorious in this regards it does lot of fetching and painting in background before actual pain happens e.g. example.com/[anything past .com is fetched as you type so your server could get number of hit before you even hit enter key]

Comment: This could explain why some browser are remembering on the fly name attribute while Chrome doesn't simply put its rendering whole thing again on every address change or page reload.

Comment: How the hack is suppose top work is on first ever load and every next load it would change the name attribute value. If one goes away from page and comes back again in every history POP event it would change the value again mimicking autocomplete off.  If it does not then our hack fails, so by this virtue hack worked. Now browser that are pulling page as an previously painted image from cache memory wont trigger all the JS rendering thus name value does not change.

Comment: Trying to remember the autocomplete value on certain occasions and forget at other times is new field altogether more like Single Page Application  where one would remember and hash value the history pop event e.g. 1,2,3  then could run function if going hash back goes down one number dont trigger hack else trigger hack.

Comment: try this go in developer mode on chrome or right click on field then inspect element, hard reload the page so every thing is fresh in right hand pan find the filed you are interacting with then note the name attribute value. In left pan type in something press enter move away from page come back see is the value changed or same. if the value is changed hack triggered if not then previous painted image happened.